# Instagram Feed on HTML site - How To Get Access Token

Tags: jquery, instagram, access-token

I am building a single page (Splash/Temp) website for a client and want to include their Instagram feed.

I have gotten instagram feeds working previously on WP sites using plugins but am having trouble following the directions on the Instagram Authentication page: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

I am trying to use the Spectragram JS Plugin: http://spectragram.js.org/

But just can't figure out how to get the access token.

Is there any chance someone is able to break it down for me in non-jargan terms please.

Comment: I'm happy to pay someone to help me out here if no one wants to give me advice. It seems like such a simple thing but I just don't understand what Auth0 is and what a redirect URI is so I cant even register a client on the Instagram developer site.

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token for instagram providing that you already have an app id.
Head over to http://instagram.com/developer. Login to your account. Then click on Manage Clients, click on the app,
then set the OAuth redirect_uri field to localhost
Paste the following url into your web browser.

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID_HERE]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token

and add the client id you generated to the url replacing "[CLIENT_ID_HERE]" (without quotes).

hint: Treat your Instagram access token like you would your password. Do not share your access token with anyone.